# Trying to use setTimeout and similar functions to generate whenever a function should occur

Tags: javascript, css, settimeout

I'm a very new JavaScript user and I'm working on re-creating something for my website, in which I'd like it to have a flash/glow effect every few seconds, with the flash only appearing for a certain amount of time.

here's what I tried:

```
let glow = true;

function flash() {
    glow = !glow;
  if(glow) {
    document.querySelector("#logo").style.textShadow = "-2px -2px 0.1em #fff, -2px -2px 0.1em #fff, 2px 2px 0.1em #fff, -2px -2px 0.3em #fff, 2px 2px 0.5em #fff";
  }
  else{
  document.querySelector("#logo").style.textShadow = "0 0 0";
  }
 } 
 
(function loop() {
    var rand = Math.round(Math.random() * (7000 - 4000)) + 4000; // supposed to be how often the flashes occur, from 7s to 4s
    var glow = setInterval(flash, 700); // supposed to be max time the flash can stay on screen
    setTimeout(function() {
            flash();
            loop();  
    }, rand);
}());
```

and I left comments describing in detail what I was going for. any help is appreciated, I just started JavaScript yesterday and mainly wrote that receiving help from other sources, so sorry if it's hard to read!

Comment: What is the current behavior? It appears to work when I tested it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You keep creating setIntervals without ever getting rid of them so the flash keeps showing, and showing and showing (and it gets more and more as time goes on, if you left it long enough the system may run out of resources!).

If you do want the flash to happen more than once in that random time interval then save the setInterval and delete it before starting another.

However, I understand you want a .7s flash once each time, so use setTimeout instead as this will happen just the once.

```html
<style>
  body {
    background: blue;
  }
</style>
<div id="logo">HELLO</div>
<script>
  let glow = true;

  function flash() {
    glow = !glow;
    if (glow) {
      document.querySelector("#logo").style.textShadow = "-2px -2px 0.1em #fff, -2px -2px 0.1em #fff, 2px 2px 0.1em #fff, -2px -2px 0.3em #fff, 2px 2px 0.5em #fff";
    } else {
      document.querySelector("#logo").style.textShadow = "0 0 0";
    }
  }

  (function loop() {
    var rand = Math.round(Math.random() * (7000 - 4000)) + 4000; // supposed to be how often the flashes occur, from 7s to 4s
    var glow = setTimeout(flash, 700); // supposed to be max time the flash can stay on screen
    setTimeout(function() {
      flash();
      loop();
    }, rand);
  }());
</script>
```

Notes:

I made the body background blue simply as a way of seeing the white flash.

There are ways in JS and CSS which would make things a bit simpler. For example using CSS animation for the timing of the flash but I appreciate you are just starting out and practising timeouts etc.

Also nowadays you will find var in JS used less frequently. It's worth learning about `const` and `let` as they help get the scope of variables more tightly defined and stop you altering things which are really constants.

Answer (score 0):

You are writing a lot for this. Just use something like the below example:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',()=>{
  function glow(){
    document.getElementById('box').classList.toggle('glow')
  }
  setInterval(glow,3000)
})
```

```css
#box{
  margin: 2rem;
  width: 8rem;
  height:8rem;
  text-align:center;
  line-height:8rem;
  background: #f2f2f2;
  transition: .5s ease;
  font-size: 3rem;
  font-weight: 700;
}
.glow{
  text-shadow: 0 0 10px #00ff00
}
```

```html
<div id="box">Hello</div>
```

Comment: Hi, while this gives neater code it does not explain what is wrong with the original code or how this new code works. Code-only answers are discouraged because they don't necessarily help learning.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks mostly correct, but there are a few adjustments you need to make to achieve the desired flash/glow effect. Here's the modified version of your code with explanations:

```js
let glow = true;

function flash() {
  glow = !glow;
  if (glow) {
    document.querySelector("#logo").style.textShadow = "-2px -2px 0.1em #fff, -2px -2px 0.1em #fff, 2px 2px 0.1em #fff, -2px -2px 0.3em #fff, 2px 2px 0.5em #fff";
  } else {
    document.querySelector("#logo").style.textShadow = "0 0 0";
  }
}

(function loop() {
  var rand = Math.round(Math.random() * (7000 - 4000)) + 4000; // Random time between 4 and 7 seconds

  flash(); // Trigger the initial flash immediately

  setTimeout(function() {
    setInterval(flash, 700); // Start the flashing at an interval of 700ms
  }, rand);
})();
```

```html
<h4 id="logo">Hi!</h4>
```

The initial flash is triggered immediately before starting the loop to ensure the first flash occurs without any delay.

Instead of using a separate variable for **setInterval**, we can call **setInterval** directly inside **setTimeout**. This will start the flashing at an interval of 700ms after the random delay.

The **setInterval** function doesn't need to be stored in a variable since we don't need to clear it later. We want the flashing to continue indefinitely.

With these adjustments, the code should produce the desired flash/glow effect with flashes occurring every few seconds.